# How .NET Core is implemented in order to support multiple operating systems

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to know, why the applications built on .Net framework is not Cross Platform (at Operating System Level) and why the applications built on .net core framework is CROSS Platform.

I know new CLR's (Runtime) for every Operating System's (Windows, Linux and mac os) is created, These Operating System specific CLR's will convert the common IL into Operating System Specific instructions, so do this the only new major change?.

I am not talking about performance changes in .net Core and want to know, How the traditional .Net framework is made cross-platform at OS Level so that it became Operating System agnostic .Net Core.

Comment: You seem to be confused on the difference between .NET Framework, ASP.NET, .NET Core, and ASP.NET Core. Your title is asking about .NET Core vs .NET Framework, but your question body is asking about ASP.NET vs ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @mason: I have Updated the Title: I am not confused, I know the differences, differences are already scattered on the web,  What really I want to know is what I have written in the question body. It seems that you have not understand my question

Comment: I didn't understand your question because you confused it with your title which was asking something completely different than the body of your question. ASP.NET Core runs on top of .NET Framework or .NET Core, which was designed to run cross platform. ASP.NET runs on top of .NET Framework, which is only available on Windows. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @mason : not really, I want to know, Why the applications built on ASP.Net framework is not Cross Platform (at Operating System Level) and why the applications built on ASP.net core framework is Cross Platform. Meaning What changes are done in Core, which results in into cross-platform.

Comment: I answered that already. ASP.NET runs on .NET Framework, which is only on Windows. ASP.NET Core can run on .NET Core, which is available for Windows, Mac and Linux. Perhaps the question you really mean to ask is: "why does .NET Framework run only in Windows while .NET Core can run everywhere?"

Comment: @mason: cool!. So my question is "why does .NET Framework run only in Windows while .NET Core can run everywhere". What is in .Net core, which made it CROSS PLATFORM

Comment: Because .NET Framework was written to use API's that are available on Windows. You could reimplement those in such a way that it's cross platform, that's what the [Mono framework](https://www.mono-project.com) is.

Comment: @mason : Cool, But can you share me some such concrete api's or changes. I exactly want to know those implementations

Comment: Well there's the obvious: only Windows has IIS and Windows services and the registry. But there's more subtle things, like the .NET Framework is designed to use Win32 APIs for interacting with the file system and the networking stack, not those provided by *nix systems. The list goes on and on. Of course, these are just academic questions you're asking. Why do you want to know these things? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @mason : That is a cool!! one. as I am new to CORE so I am trying to figure out the reason behind the .NET core platform independence behaviour.  Can you share me the links of any such blogs listings such API and changes

Comment: .NET Core is an entire rewrite. The reasons for pursuing cross platform are well documented if you look for them. And Stack Overflow is here to answer specific concrete questions, not go off in search of blog posts for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some research around it (Also in discussion with @mason (in comments)), Below is the concrete answer, Which I thought, I should share with everyone.

.net core contains platform specific and platform-neutral implementations (libraries). This is done through separate implementations and conditional compilation as per each platform.

One Such CoreFX (a foundational class libraries for .NET Core): This library contains both Platform-specific and platform-neutral code. Its platform-neutral code is shared across all platforms. Such as:

- System.IO and System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms are
  platform-specific, given that storage and cryptography APIs are different on each OS.
- System.Collections and System.Linq are platform-neutral.

Also Apart from libraries CLR's is (CoreCLR in core) is platform-specific. It builds on top of OS subsystems, like the memory manager and thread scheduler.